# using hover on a div not working

Tags: css, html, hover

You can visit the site [here](http://thomashall.idesignclass.com/portfolio/#portfolio) (click "portfolio" to get to the relevant part for this question).

I am trying to set up a title to appear when an image is hovered over. I formatted the images as well as the text to appear upon hovering. I set the div's visibility to hidden and used the hover tag to make it visible, but it refuses to reappear upon hovering. How can I make the div actually appear upon hovering?

Here's my HTML (just the first li to keep the post short)

```
<li>
  <a href="#openModal1">
    <div class="imgwrap">
      <img src="portfolio_images/poster.png">
      <div class="textwrap"><p class="imgdes">Pedalfest Poster</p></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

And the CSS

```
.imgwrap {
height:150px; width:150px;
}

.textwrap {
position:absolute;
width:150px; height:30px;
background-color:#727272;
margin-top:-30px;
visibility: hidden;
}

.imgdes {
text-align:center; font-family: Droid serif, serif;
font-weight:500; font-size:14px;
line-height:30px;
text-decoration:none; color:#f7f7f7;
top:50%;
}

.textwrap:hover {
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: You can't hover over a ``visibility: hidden`` or ``display: none`` styled element as there is nothing for the mouse to hover over.

Comment: try using javascript onmouseover="function()"... to show/hide the description box.

Comment: i think you should try this for better animation effect when hovered. check this out http://geekgirllife.com/place-text-over-images-on-hover-without-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the visibility when you hover over the container.  You can do something like:

```
.imgwrap:hover .textwrap {
     visibility: visible;
}
```

You are simply using the hovering over the `imgwrap` class to control the properties of `textwrap`.  Essentially you are just using the hovering over the parent but then specifying a child; in this case, `textwrap`.  Since you can't hover over an element that is hidden, we hover over it's parent, which is the area over which we want to be able to hover anyway.

Comment: Just did. Does that help?

Comment: This works exactly as I need it to. I will mark as correct as soon as the time limit expires.

Comment: @bjb567 It is exactly because of what Adam said in the first comment on the OP.  You can't hover over an element that is hidden, so in this case, we want to use the parent, which is the exact area that we want to be able to hover over anyway.

Comment: @Sam So add that to your answer to make it complete.